BasticTextField2 does not show keyboard again after hiding it
I'm facing this issue. Using the new BasicTextField2 API, after hiding the keyboard with the back key of the Android navigation bar and trying to show it again by pressing on the BasicTextField2, the keyboard does not show again. I was going to fix this issue by showing the keyboard programatically but it seems that BasicTextField2 does not detect pressed events.
// Compose
var value by remember {
    mutableStateOf("")
}
val interactionSource = remember {
    MutableInteractionSource()
}

val pressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
val focused by interactionSource.collectIsFocusedAsState()

Log.d("CustomTextFieldEvents", "----------------------------")
Log.d("CustomTextFieldEvents: ", "Pressed: $pressed")
Log.d("CustomTextFieldEvents: ", "Focused: $focused")
Log.d("CustomTextFieldEvents", "----------------------------")

BasicTextField2(
    modifier = modifier,
    value = value,
    onValueChange = { newValue ->
        value = newValue
    },
    interactionSource = interactionSource
)

I only get in the logcat when I tap on it:
CustomTextFieldEvents   com.marmatsan.app                    D  ----------------------------
CustomTextFieldEvents:  com.marmatsan.app                    D  Pressed: false
CustomTextFieldEvents:  com.marmatsan.app                    D  Focused: true
CustomTextFieldEvents   com.marmatsan.app                    D  ----------------------------

Changing it with the old BasicTextField works. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Are you using jetpack compose ?

@Maveňツ BasicTextfield2 is only available in  compose

in one of my project i solved it by upgrading to alpha version of material3 library i suggest u wait for the stable build also it is now merged with BasicTextField in latest alpha version

The solution is to clearFocus when keyboard is hidden.  See
How can I show a composable on top of the visible Keyboard?
